# Google drive api uploaded file but return 500 error

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm uploading file to google drive by using service account. And It worked w/o any problem for a while.
And it started giving 500 error from 2 days ago.

```
W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
W/System.err: {
W/System.err:   "code" : 500,
W/System.err:   "message" : null
W/System.err: }
```

But there is file uploaded successfully if I go to gdrive account in web and only success usage in console also. ( only 200 responses )

Answer (score 2):

Based on  [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error) '*500: Backend Error*' is an unexpected error occurred while processing the request. The suggested action is to use  [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

*Exponential backoff* is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. Exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors.

You may also check this stack overflow related ticket which discuss some other work around: [Google Drive uploading file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769000/google-drive-uploading-file-size-limit)

Comment: Well it was not able to resolved by either retry or size limit unless thumbnailLink field is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It's fixed by removing 'thumbnailLink' field. I used to work but started to giving error about a week ago.

From

```
Drive.Files.Create insert = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id,mimeType,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink");
```

To

```
Drive.Files.Create insert = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id,mimeType,webContentLink,webViewLink");
```