# Google Drive Rest API V3 Update fails when thumbnailLink field is asked in reponse

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-apis-explorer

When I do an files.update call and ask the thumbnailLink field to be included in the response, the file is actually updated but the API returns a 500-error. When I remove the thumbnailLink field, everything works fine. I can reproduce this issue with [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update#request-body)

- **Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?**

**Request**

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1B......ID.......?fields=id%2CthumbnailLink
```

**Response**

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

**Request**

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1B......ID.......?fields=id
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "1B......ID......."
}
```

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101162/google-drive-api-uploaded-file-but-return-500-error/36170317#36170317) with files.insert, but no solution given.

Comment: Yes its related.  500 is normally flood protection try and send it again see if it gets accepted. I would recommend implementing exponential back-off in your code   I like to call it a server hiccup.

Comment: @DalmTo: In this case it is not related to the Flood protection. It happens always, no matter when you do the request call. You will see it when you try the call via the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update#request-body)

Comment: I would log it as a bug then v3 is still new its likely that it could be a bug https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=API%3DDrive

Comment: Posting the link of [issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4574), you should follow this to be updated about the progress. Hope this helps

Comment: I've filed the issue with the engineering team. Star it to get updates.